# Custom animated Tabbar android

Tags: android, tabs

i want to create Tab bar like below image , 
when user tap on any button that button comes to center

[image]

thanks

Comment: have you tried something or not?

Comment: i use android Android Gallery view , and on its Click listener i inflate View , but i cant customize Gallery view much